# Basic Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, axioms

Teaching myself basic group theory as part of a physics self study program and was wondering why we don’t need to axiomatize the concept that if two elements are equal, applying the operator to each results in equal elements.

$x=y$ implies 
$a•x=a•y$

Comment: This is the definition of functions. Let $f:X\to Y$, then by definition, for each $x\in X$, there is *exactly* one $y\in Y$ with $f(x)=y$. In this case we say the function is well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group theory is studied in the framework of set theory and, given two sets $A$ and $B$ and a function $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$, it is true that, if $a,b\in A$ and $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten that groups are sets and didn’t consider that the binary operator of groups are just functions. Makes sense.

Comment: @user175324 If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Of course. How do I do that? Newbie.

Comment: @user175324 Click the ✓ mark to the left of my answer, below the downvote arrow.

Comment: Done. Had to go to desktop site. App and mobile sites don’t show it.

Comment: @user175324 Thank you. Note that you can always change your mind later, if a better answer is posted.